# Converting image from project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to convert a image in my image folder and the image name `defaultImage` and update into my database table.

But now I am having problem in this line of code:

I change the code using this:

`Image uploaded6 = Image.FromFile("/image/defaultImage.jpg");`

instead of this:

`System.Drawing.Image uploaded = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(`~/images/defaultImage`);`

I now getting the error of `FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code`

I have tried this method using fileupload control and it working fine but not sure how to convert image in a folder.

How do I get the image from the folder in order to convert it using the method shown below.

```
Image uploaded6 = Image.FromFile("/image/defaultImage.jpg");

//System.Drawing.Image uploaded = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream();

System.Drawing.Image newImage = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(uploaded, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
}

byte[] results;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
    EncoderParameters jpegParms = new EncoderParameters(1);
    jpegParms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 95L);
    newImage.Save(ms, codec, jpegParms);
    results = ms.ToArray();
}

string sqlImage = "update MemberReport set image1 = @Data where memberreportid = '" + Session["memberreportid"] + "'";
SqlCommand cmdImage = new SqlCommand(sqlImage);
cmdImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", results);
InsertUpdateData(cmdImage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is with relative paths, instead of

```
Image uploaded6 = Image.FromFile("/image/defaultImage.jpg");
```

you should provide the local path, which you can get it this way:

```
Image uploaded6 = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/image/defaultImage.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

System.Drawing.Image.FromStream requires  'MemoryStream' as parameter.

```
 byte[] file = null;
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 memoryStream = new MemoryStream(file, false);

 System.Drawing.Image objTempImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
```

byte[] file is based64 image

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream)
```

You must to send a Stream parameter in this method.